# image disappears which uploaded with managed_file type

Tags: 7, hooks

I have implemented a configuration page which is at admin panel. It is something like this:

```
  $form["footer"]['xyz_cust_image'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => t('Image title'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('xyz_cust_image'),
    "#description" => t("Image description"),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#upload_location' => 'public://',
    '#upload_validators' => array(
      'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg')
    )
  );
```

but have a different situation. the thing is I successfully upload image and it is appearing when i upload it at the browser for that day. When the day passed, the image disappears. When I looked to variable table, the record exists; but the image not appears.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drupal prunes files that haven't been explicitly marked as permanent. This happens on a cron job, which explains the delay you're seeing.

To avoid this, you need to add a submit handler to your form which updates the status of the file. e.g.

```
MYMODULE_some_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $file = file_load($form_state['values']['xyz_cust_image']);
  $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
  file_save($file);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. How can I run that cron again to test that bug really fixed? I run directly from admin panel but that it does not change anything. Image is appearing. Is there an another way to trigger that cron job?

Comment: @udogan Non-permanent files are cleared after 6 hours of uploading or so. So instead of waiting you can just open the database (if you have access) and check the status of the file in the `file_managed` table.

Comment: You can trigger it manually using the `system_cron()` function, but that's exactly the same as running it through the UI